# Angular 2 method is not subscribing to the observable

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get JSON data using a Service class.
**Service class**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { GeneralTab }     from './generalTab';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class GeneralTabService {
     constructor(private _http : Http) {

        console.log("Http call");
    }

   getStatus(): Observable<any>  {
    return      this._http.get('http://samd.server.lan.at/taskmanagement/rest/taskconfigs/IND?language=EN&access_token=200')
         .map((res:Response) => <GeneralTab[]>res.json())
         .do(data => console.log("All: " +  JSON.stringify(data)))
         .catch(this.handleError);

}
  private handleError (error: any) {
    
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**Component class**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GeneralTab} from "./generalTab";
import {GeneralTabService} from "./generalTab.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Component({
        selector: 'general-tab',
        templateUrl: '/general.component.html',
        providers : [GeneralTabService]

    })

    export class GeneralComponent implements OnInit{
        title = 'Serving data from General Component';

        errorMessage: any;
        status: GeneralTab [];
        mode = 'Observable';

        constructor (private generalService: GeneralTabService) {
            this.status = [];
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            console.log("Started");
            this.generalService.getStatus().subscribe(
                (status: any) => this.status = status,
                (error: any) =>  this.errorMessage = error
            );
            console.log(this.status);
        }

    }
```

**GeneralTab class**

```
export class GeneralTab {

    constructor(public recipientId : string,
    public recipientName: string,
    public recipientFullname: string,
    public ouId:String,
    public ouName:String,
    public institute:number,
    public shortName:String,
    public status:String)
    {
    }
}
```

I see in the console that **.do(data => console.log("All:" +  JSON.stringify(data)))** is getting me JSON data like

{"subjectsConfig":[{"subject":"Client Data Maintenance","preselected":false,"initialDueDate":"2016-11-24","actionConfigs":[{"action":"SEND","recipients":[{"user":{"recipientId":"BD27A4F5923FCA13","recipientName":"ABTABT","recipientFullname":"ABTABT","ouId":"BD27A4F5923FCA13","ouName":"0015",....

Subscribe is not assigning any data to status array and I'm getting blank "status" array. I want this data as an array in status variable for testing purpose. How do I get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log the response like

```
 console.log("Started");
 this.generalService.getStatus().subscribe(
         (status: any) => this.status = status,
         (error: any) =>  this.errorMessage = error
 );
 console.log(this.status);
```

Of course you will see a blank status since the above code(`getStatus().subscribe`) is async. Meaning you are making a request then you are waiting for the response inside `subscribe` and when it comes, you will assign `status` to `this.status`. While waiting you are already logging(`this.status`) which is initially blank.

Instead try this and check the log,

```
 console.log("Started");
 this.generalService.getStatus().subscribe(
       (status: any) => {
            this.status = status;
            console.log(this.status);
       },
       (error: any) =>  this.errorMessage = error
 );
```